# Facebook login with Firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication

I am following below URL demo and setup same thing but getting error below.

https://www.positronx.io/build-firebase-login-with-facebook-in-angular/

**The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.**

Any one can help on it? i am using angular.

Comment: Did you do what the message asked you to?

Comment: @CBroe yes already done 
1. Added domain
2. Added Website URL
3. Added Oauth return URL

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"